# Set dbunit schema in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, dbunit

I am writing tests with dbunit and h2 and I have a table "users" that seems to be conflicting with the public schema in h2 and I can't assert the database after the test

When I change the table name the test passes.

I think I need to change the database schema used in dbunit.
How can I change the dbunit database schema using Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

As this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108123/5279345 says, you should set `qualifiedTableNames` to true, but I still couldn't find how to do this..